# dbunit assertion not throwing failure properly

Tags: java, maven, junit, assert, dbunit

Following is a test case which tests the working of **org.dbunit.Assertion.assertEquals(ITable a, ITable b)**

```
@Test
public void testAssertion() {
    try {
        //Creating actual table with 2 columns
        DefaultTable actual = new DefaultTable("table_name",
                new Column[] { new Column("col1", DataType.INTEGER),
                        new Column("col2", DataType.VARCHAR) });
        actual.addRow(new Object[] { 1, "ABCD" });
        actual.addRow(new Object[] { 2, "BABCD" });
        actual.addRow(new Object[] { 3, "CCGF" });

        //Creating expected table with same 2 columns
        DefaultTable expected = new DefaultTable(expected
                .getTableMetaData());
        expected.addRow(new Object[] { 1, "ABCD" });
        expected.addRow(new Object[] { 2, "BBCD" });

        // Check the actual vs expected
        Assertion.assertEquals(actual, expected);
        //This should return a test failure since actual & expected are different.
        //But its not throwing any test case failure.
    } catch (DataSetException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DatabaseUnitException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here both the DefaultTable's values are mismatched and still JUnit is not failing the above testcase. I am running it from the eclipse and it results in 0 Errors and 0 Failures with an Unrooted Tests under the testcase like as follows,

```
    testAssertion [Runner: JUnit 4]
[+] Unrooted Tests [Runner: JUnit 4]
```

I debugged the DBUnit API and it is throwing data mismatch exception as required, but finally when returning from SpringJUnit4ClassRunner it is not thrown as a test case failure.

I suppose something I am missing here. Pls correct me or let me know a solution for this. 
Thanks in advace.

Comment: All I can say is, keep making your example more and more simple until you find out what's going on.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for ur feedback. I ve added some comments to make it more understandable and I couldn't go further simplest on this example and error still persists. If it is throwing any error i could ve done some googling, but its not throwing any failure/errors :(

Answer (score -1):

Assertion is DBUnit throws AssertionError.

What I found the best way to get the exact exception reason was to catch it, for example:-

```
try
{
     Assertion.assertEquals( expectedTable, actualTable );
}
catch ( AssertionError e )
{
     logger.error( "Assertion failed with error : " + e.getMessage());
}
```